# Accessing directories in Unix using Java

Tags: java, unix, directory

I  tried  Googling but  was unable to come up with any results. What I'm looking for is a basic explanation or tutorial on howto navigate  a Unix server with Java.

I have several Java programs that I would like to run directly on my server, however I just have no idea how to let these programs go to certain directories, or scan certain files, etc.

How exactly can I use Java with Unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html). Specify a path, see if it is a directory, open it, read it, delete it, etc, etc, etc.

[listFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) will give the files within a directory.

Comment: Much appreciated I just had no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easier use Apache commons-io FileUtils -> http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Here is the project home page -> http://commons.apache.org/io/

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find simplest guides:

1. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/
2. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm
3. http://home.cogeco.ca/~ve3ll/jatutor9.htm